# while deploying changesets i am getting error of unauthorised organization

Tags: salesforce, admin

i want to deploy some classes from sandbox to production but while uploading i am getting dis following error.
"**This organization isn't authorized to upload change sets to other organizations. For authorization, contact the deployment connections administrators on the organizations where you want to upload changes.**" guys what i should do? the same error is showing when deploying from production to sandbox also.i think i missed some steps. Can somebody suggest what steps should i take now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deployment isn't authorized on the production salesforce account, you'll need to log in there and enable it (or ask an admin in that org to do so)

From here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dev_lifecycle.meta/dev_lifecycle/migrate_deployment_connection.htm

Before you can receive change sets from a sandbox or other organization, authorize a deployment connection in the organization that receives the changes.

1. Log into the organization that’ll receive inbound change sets.
   Usually this is the production organization associated with your
   sandbox.
2. From Setup, enter Deployment in the Quick Find box, then
   select Deployment Settings.
3. Click Edit next to the organization from which you want to receive outbound   change sets. Usually this is your sandbox.
4. Select Allow Inbound Changes and click Save.

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect the organizations. In the org of the deployment, you can activate the connection from the setup.